# Program completely stops Python 3

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I have a problem where my program won't continue, it's Python 3 and I'd appreciate all possible solutions.

I have a class called BotInit, which initializes the sockets and stuff for a bot I'm making, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with any sockets. There's a method called Begin, here it is, the program stops after

```
Bot.Bot()
```

okay so, here's the method:

```
    def Begin(self):
    R = self.Socket.Recv()
    if(R.find('<bot') != -1):
        try:
            bot = ElementTree.fromstring(R.strip(chr(0))).attrib
            Bot = Bot.Bot()
            print('heeey')
            Bot.ID = bot['u']
            Bot.Auth = bot['auth']
            Bot.Database = MySQL.MySQL().CreateConnection()
            Bot.LoadSelf()
            c = CreateBot.CreateBot(Bot)
            c.AuthorizeBot()
        except:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Okay and here's the Bot class:

```
class Bot:
ID = None
Auth = None
Nickname = None
OwnerID = None
UID = None
K1 = None
Avatar = None
Homepage = None
Chat = None
Database = None
Socket = None

def __init__(self):
    pass

def LoadSelf(self):
    user = self.Database.GetUserByID(self.ID)
    self.Nickname = user["Nickname"]
    self.OwnerID = user["OwnerID"]
    self.UID = user["UID"]
    self.K1 = user["K1"]
    self.Avatar = user["Avatar"]
    self.Homepage = user["Homepage"]
    self.Chat = user["Chat"]
```

Alright so, as I said, the program stops after Bot.Bot(), and I really need help, as I'm stuck and idk what to do. I used the "heyyy" output just to know where it stops.
Thanks

Comment: Your blanket except is not going to be very informative, what happens if you remove the try/except?

Comment: again show finger and want `full check-up` !

Comment: Thanks Padaric, I forgot that I caught the exceptions so the errors didn't show, now that I know the errors, I can fix them myself. Much appreciated.

Comment: @iMixx, no worries, always try to catch specific exceptions and/or at least log or print the error so you will be able to debug easily